# Keeps "SSH timeout" error in our AWS instance- how do i diagnose?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, uptime

I am befuddled by this error. We keep failing to SSH into our AWS instance, whether it is is deployment or via console. I have tried rebooting a few times, but it does not seem to be helping.

Here are a couple of error messages i keep getting.

> connection failed for: HOST.NAME.amazonaws.com (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))
>
> 111.222.333.444: ssh connection failed at 2010-07-02 03:39:37

I also SSHed in when it was up, and monitored "top" when ssh times out. looking at the memory logs, it does not look like any program was hogging

Answer (score 1):

To help diagnosis add this to your client's ssh_config:

# Check every 60s
`ServerAliveInterval 60`
 # Timeout after 40m
`ServerAliveCountMax 40`

Answer (score 0):

Add ssh to your security group e.g. via aws console https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home